# Forward and Backward Slash in Json after conversion

Tags: python, json, csvtojson

I am currently converting a csv file to a json file using a python code and is further sent as a response to an API. After converting to Json file, Date fields in the json have a forward and backward slash in between whereas in csv its not.

**Date in csv**:

```
"2023/04/13"
```

**Date field after conversion**:

```
"certification_date":"2023\/04\/13"
```

Backward slash (`\`) is also being added at some blank spaces.

Why is this appended and when can we expect this?

Comment: How do you look at the resulting JSON? Do you use `print` in the Python code, or do you open the JSON file in a text editor, or...?

Comment: And what Python code do you use to convert the CSV to JSON?

Comment: we can help you when you share your codebase

Comment: It’s perfectly okay for slashes to be escaped in JSON. That doesn’t make the backslashes actually part of the data.

Comment: Please show the code that causes this behavior. Be sure to show only the code that does this and not all of your code if this is part of a larger program.